# Mux audio and video UWP using Mediacomposition

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to merge a video with an audio acc downloaded from youtube but the script is freezing my machine using 100% of my CPU and the result file is too big in size, ex : the downloaded audio and 720p video are in total 80MB the transcoded video will be 400MB (for 720p and for 4K video the app crash).

I've tried to copy the downloaded HD video properties to create a **MediaEncodingProfile** from it, but its not working all I get is pixeled video knowing that the downloaded is an HD 720 video.
here is code:

```
public IAsyncOperation<IStorageFile> MergeAudioandVideoHDAsync(StorageFile videoFile, StorageFile audioFile, string finalFileName, StorageFolder destinationFolder)
    {
        return Task.Run<IStorageFile>(async () =>
        {
            IStorageFile _OutputFile = await destinationFolder.CreateFileAsync(finalFileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            MediaComposition _MediaComposition = new MediaComposition();
            var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(videoFile);
            _MediaComposition.Clips.Add(clip);
            //Adding Background Audio Track
            _MediaComposition.BackgroundAudioTracks.Add(await BackgroundAudioTrack.CreateFromFileAsync(audioFile));
            MediaEncodingProfile _MediaEncodingProfile =  MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD720p);
            TranscodeFailureReason _TranscodeFailureReason = await _MediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync(_OutputFile, MediaTrimmingPreference.Fast, _MediaEncodingProfile);

            if (_TranscodeFailureReason != TranscodeFailureReason.None)
            {
                throw new Exception("Video Concatenation Failed: " + _TranscodeFailureReason.ToString());
            }
            return _OutputFile;

        }).AsAsyncOperation();
    }
```

Thanks

**EDIT :**

The problem here is the **CPU consumption at 100%** for a 720p and above Video rendering, how to avoid that, it freezes my machine!

Answer (score 0):

[MediaComposition. RenderToFileAsync(IStorageFile, MediaTrimmingPreference, MediaEncodingProfile)](https://apac01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fuwp%2Fapi%2Fwindows.media.editing.mediacomposition.rendertofileasync%23Windows_Media_Editing_MediaComposition_RenderToFileAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFile_Windows_Media_Editing_MediaTrimmingPreference_Windows_Media_MediaProperties_MediaEncodingProfile_&data=02%7C01%7C%7Ceb93b1ddfdc745672d2608d653835b9a%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636788220971941033&sdata=M8LdIAiYWsG4itmVKeCNoMyK%2BtyQUX4QYDDcmpeskWM%3D&reserved=0) asynchronously renders the MediaComposition to a specified file using the indicated media trimming preference and encoding profile.

When using this method to render the composition to a file, the only factor affecting the file size is the third parameter, that is [MediaEncodingProfile](https://apac01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fuwp%2Fapi%2Fwindows.media.mediaproperties.mediaencodingprofile&data=02%7C01%7C%7Ceb93b1ddfdc745672d2608d653835b9a%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636788220971941033&sdata=KMEwbowkp67OcTC39Hrij%2Bg9uACvSjl47whtWeC1n%2Fs%3D&reserved=0). 
And when you use this class to create a mp4 file:

```
  MediaEncodingProfile _MediaEncodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD720p);
```

The [VideoEncodingQuality](https://apac01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fuwp%2Fapi%2Fwindows.media.mediaproperties.videoencodingquality%3Ff1url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmsdn.microsoft.com%252Fquery%252Fdev15.query%253FappId%253DDev15IDEF1%2526l%253DEN-US%2526k%253Dk(Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingQuality)%253Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore%252CVersion%253Dv5.0)%253Bk(DevLang-csharp)%2526rd%253Dtrue%2526f%253D255%2526MSPPError%253D-2147217396&data=02%7C01%7C%7Ceb93b1ddfdc745672d2608d653835b9a%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636788220971951038&sdata=iZdKBKZ6stOH4ZK8e8JIhdoLV4Fc%2FjYCCVhxsVZPrMc%3D&reserved=0) is an enum, different enumerated type values determine the different encodings of the file, ultimately resulting in different sizes of the file. 
Here is the test of different enumerated type values:

[image]

So please refer to the tested result to choose the suitable encoding format when you render to a mp4 file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply the size is not the problem, the code below freeze my machine using the 100% of the CPU, any hints?

Comment: @Thecoder15 It’s hard to figure out why it takes up 100% of the CPU just from this code, I can not reproduce this issue in my test, maybe there are other places in your project that affect this effect, I recommend you that add some breakpoints to debug the code, which line to run will cause waste of CPU.

Or provide a MCVE, the audio and video files, also please provide the OS version, project target version and the min version.

Comment: Thank you again, I think its because of parallels VM (running on Macbook pro retina 2106) that I'm using wich it supports only Directx 10